# Консоль/Терминал в Андроид

Tags: android, terminal, терминал

Android основана на **Linux** и принадлежит к их семейству. Но существует ли в них самый главный компонент, на самом деле не такой уж и главный, а именно – терминал?

То есть могу ли я обратиться непосредственно из самой ОС, которая предоставлена пользователю, к командной строке, и, допустим, пуститься в далекие путешествия как на обычной *nix системе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, выбирай [какой нравится](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=terminal)
Но учти, что пользователю доступно не так уж и много.
Для полного доступа необходимы root-права на устройство.

Самым популярным способом получения root прав считаю [Framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276). Поддерживает большинство устройств, [проверь своё](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/framaroot-supported-devices-t2722980).

**Важно!!!**

**Получение root прав на устройстве снимает устройство с гарантии**

Так что на свой страх и риск.